# Aggregate in SQLite or Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, aggregate

Suppose I have a table with a article headers, author, and also a publication date, I retrieve all of the ones that are published after July 1st, - but now I want to iterate through not the article headers individually, but through sets of all the articles published on each day, what's the best and most pythonic way to build this list. Can it be done in the sqlite query?

Edit: I don't actually have a table with articles in sqlite3, but let's suppose I did. And suppose the table `articles` is organized with:

```
title TEXT, author TEXT, publisher TEXT, date DATETIME
```

The articles might be fetched like so:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM articles where date > ?", \ 
(datetime.datetime(2014, 07, 01),))
```

and could be grouped by (Following Holdenweb's answer below):

> itertools.groupby(cursor.fetchall(), lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[3], '%Y-%m-%d
>   %H:%M:%S.%f').day)

which will give a tuple of (day, group), and can be iterated over in the manner described below.

Comment: @user4367349 What have you done so far?

Comment: If I had done it I wouldn't be on here asking a question, right? I guess very naively I can run a for loop on the returned set of articles put them into a list and put that list in another list. But I'm sure there is a much better way.

Comment: SO is supposed to help you with resolving specific programming related problems. SO is not "write me this kind of code" service.

Comment: This is a general question that is useful for all types of problems needing a group of lists rather than just one sorted list. If you have nothing constructive to add, move on.

Comment: Please, look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . Even general questions can be provided with piece of code, which allows showing solution in real. Do not worry, I am moving on.

Comment: There you go I edited my question.

Comment: +1, well done. Ideally there would be short dump from SQLite database, allowing to do the test in real, but I am aware, this takes some time to prepare. Thank you for your effort to understand my previous comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SQL query will normally only return a single set of rows as a result.

Let's say you have retrieved all the rows you want in a cursor `curs`, and assume that the resulting rows are each made up of `(header, author, pub_date)` and that you sorted the data in SQL in ascending order of pub_date.

Using [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) it's very easy to define a key function that returns the pub_date colum (`lambda r: r[2]` comes to mind). You can then iterate over the `groupby()` result which is a series of `(key_value, group)` tuples where `key_value` will take the successive unique values of the `pub_date` column and `group` will be an iterator yielding successive rows associated with that key value. Try something like

```
for key_val, group in itertools.groupby(curs.fetchall(), lambda r: r[2]):
    print key_val
    for item in group:
        print "\t", item
```

to verify this works as you want.

Comment: itertools.groupby is exactly what I was looking for, ++ !

Comment: Of course if you retrieve the pub-date as the first element you won't need a key function at all, a further simplification - just make the elements `(pub_date, author, header)`.

Comment: Side question, it seems doing this my_list = list(itertools.groupby(s, lambda x: x[0]) does not work as expected. Is there a preferred method to access the values by key or iterate several times? I can post a separate question if you think that's wise. Also there may be cases where one would want to map to a dictionary rather than a tuple - is that doable?