# Multiplying values within a column

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 through python 2.7.

I have a table where I would like to multiply values in column C where column B is the same.

If these values were in different columns it would be a lot more simple 
I could just use

`SELECT B, C1 *C2 FROM table1;`

But I am lost when it comes to multiplying within a column.

For example if this is original table

```
A   B      C
1   Mike   2.5
1   Susan  4.2
1   Patti  2.0
2   Susan  1.1
2   Patti  3.7
3   Mike   0.2
```

Then where the entrys in column B are the same, their values in column C are multiplied together, so my output would be

```
A      B
Mike   0.5
Susan  4.62
Patti  7.4
```

Comment: This needs a `PRODUCT()` aggregate function (like `SUM()`, but multiplies instead of adding), but there isn't such a thing.

Comment: See https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html for how to create custom aggregate functions in SQLite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, it is very difficult to create an aggregate function for multiplication in SQLite. However, you can work around it by using `itertools.groupby` to perform the combination and multiplication operations and then create a new table. This answer utilizes a context manager and property decorators to create a clean class call:

```
import sqlite3
import itertools
class UpdateTable:
   def __init__(self, *args):
     self.__dict__ = dict(zip(['table', 'filename'], args))
     self.new_table = None
   @property
   def newtable(self):
      return self.new_table
   @newtable.setter
   def newtable(self, new_table_name):
      self.new_table = new_table_name
   def __enter__(self):
       data = map(lambda (a, b, c):[b, float(c)], list(sqlite3.connect(self.filename).cursor().execute('SELECT * FROM {}'.format(self.table))))
       self.new_data = [(a, reduce(lambda x, y:x[-1]*y[-1], list(b))) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
       return self
   def __exit__(self):
       conn = sqlite3.connect(self.filename)
       conn.execute('CREATE TABLE {} (A text, B float)'.format(self.new_table))
       conn.executemany('INSERT INTO {} VALUES (?, ?)'.format(self.new_table), self.new_data)
       conn.commit()
       conn.close()


with UpdateTable('table', 'db_file.db') as t:
   t.newtable = 'table2'
```

Python3 requires `functools` for `reduce` and is not compatible with lambda tuple unpacking.

**Python3 version:**

```
import functools
import sqlite3
import itertools
class UpdateTable:
   def __init__(self, *args):
     self.__dict__ = dict(zip(['table', 'filename'], args))
     self.new_table = None
   @property
   def newtable(self):
      return self.new_table
   @newtable.setter
   def newtable(self, new_table_name):
      self.new_table = new_table_name
   def __enter__(self):
      data = map(lambda x:[x[1], float(x[-1])], list(sqlite3.connect(self.filename).cursor().execute('SELECT * FROM {}'.format(self.table))))
      self.new_data = [(a, functools.reduce(lambda x, y:x[-1]*y[-1], list(b))) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
      return self
   def __exit__(self):
      conn = sqlite3.connect(self.filename)
      conn.execute('CREATE TABLE {} (A text, B float)'.format(self.new_table))
      conn.executemany('INSERT INTO {} VALUES (?, ?)'.format(self.new_table), self.new_data)
      conn.commit()
      conn.close()


with UpdateTable('table', 'db_file.db') as t:
   t.newtable = 'table2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just Python, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696351/aggregate-in-sqlite-or-python#24696815). You can sort your query by column `B`, and then use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20groupby#itertools.groupby) to group the results of your query into packets which you then process using [the `reduce` built-in](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
curs.execute("SELECT id, user, number FROM table WHERE condition() ORDER BY user")

for person, group in itertools.groupby(curs.fetchall(), lambda row: row[1]):
    product = reduce((lambda a,b: a*b), [r[2] for r in group])
    do_something_with(person, product)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way by using group_concat() with a convenient delimiter:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
db.execute('create table t(A,B,C)')
db.execute('''
insert into t values
  (1,'Mike',2.5),
  (1,'Susan',4.2),
  (1,'Patti',2.0),
  (2,'Susan',1.1),
  (2,'Patti',3.7),
  (3,'Mike',0.2)
''')

for b,expr in db.execute('''select b,group_concat(c,'*') from t group by b'''):
  #print(f'{b:10s} {eval(expr):5.2f}')            #Python 3.6
  print('%-10s %5.2f' % (b,eval(expr)))            #Python 2.7
```

Comment: I tried this way but I get the error 'can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str''

Comment: You mean you copy pasted the above code and got an error?  It works for me under Python 2.7 and Python 3.6 giving the expected answer.  Try adding a `print(expr)` right under the `for` and see if there is anything unexpected in the expression (in which case you need to correct your data).  The only way I could get a similar error as you said is if any value in column C contains **nested** quotes, e.g., `(3,'Mike',"  '0.2' ")`

Comment: I'm wrong, I was rephrasing it into my own code but yours works fine.